# Infer class generic property method return type

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I'm having trouble inferring the return type of class generic property.

I have this simple setup that works:

```
class A<T extends B> {
  constructor(public b: T) {}

  getB() {
    return this.b
  }

  bMethodResult() {
    return this.b.methodOne()
  }
}

class B {
  methodOne() {
    return { status: 'ok' }
  }
}

const aOne = new A(new B())

aOne.getB() // :B

aOne.bMethodResult() // {status:string}
```

As you can see TS correctly infers the return type of `aOne.bMethodResult()`.
However, if I try to pass in a child of the `B` class with a different method signature, TS is not updating the return type to be the `B` child class method.

```
class BChild extends B {
  methodOne() {
    return { status: 'ok', data: true }
  }
}

const aTwo = new A(new BChild())

aTwo.getB() // : BChild // ok

aTwo.bMethodResult() // : {status:string }
// I want it to be {status:string, data:boolean}
```

Is there a way I could get the return type of the **child** class?

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAECCA8AVaBTAHgFxQOwCYwCEA+aAbwFgAoaaYAe2wgwCcBXYDO5gCgAdWARiACWwaAIBc0RAEoyAXypUaAcxQYC3ORWo1ozda2bZoGABbCIAOgHLoiynYEBZdWbq4ASigisQGLTI7GgMMIxNzSxsrAFs3DwB5bBQtOwcHKlBIQiDdOPNE5MCdPX1DYzJoJjAwiCkAcjoAa3r7NKoMyiyoaAIAYQsQXFRMHHxe3Jp891wklO1gsrCK0iqMGtY66EaWgBpoXBqwKRZWFDbddKUuhiZoMDnoAF5oZIB3OG533q0Za4fklY1BpAgB6UHQCQEf5zGyuApeHx+AJycFkaq1CRMZjCbAqTr0RgYe6IN50Z6vFAfWBfKm9AbCIa-f6kuhA9SaVEQqT9Qa4FlkuHxRG+fxg7no9aY7G4lQXNEASWgbzA2GJwmJnHE51IGM2WJYsv2h3WEgEdDoIBQqocQA)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this by adding a return type to `bMethodResult`:

```
class A<T extends B> {
  // ...

  bMethodResult(): ReturnType<T['methodOne']> {
    return this.b.methodOne() as ReturnType<T['methodOne']>
  }
}

// ...

aTwo.bMethodResult() // : {status:string, data: boolean}
```

However, this requires a type assertion because TypeScript infers `this.b.methodOne()` to be `{status: string}` instead of `ReturnType<T['methodOne']>`.

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAECCA8AVaBTAHgFxQOwCYwCEA+aAbwFgAoaaYAe2wgwCcBXYDO5gCgAdWARiACWwaAIBc0RAEoyAXypUaAcxQYC3ORWo1ozda2bZoGABbCIAOgHLoiynYEBZdWbq4ASigisQGLSlvDCNsRABPXhQkAG0AcgBbNw8AeWwUOIBdEh09fUNjUwtrASsk81T0rWhIaGDQiKjYxOTcNIzsuwcHKlBIQjI7cvc2qu07GgMQwtJoJjAQiCk4ugBrOPsuqh7KPqhoAgBhCxBcVEwcfAPB3WHKlGrcvSnQsjmMBdYl6BX1gBpoLgFmApCxWChNrpukpdgwmDV2tAALzQdIAdzg3HRBy0MhhYHaVjUGmqAHpSdAJAR8YSXK1vL5-GSKaR5osJExmMJsCodvRGBgaog0XRkaiUBjYFiJQdjsJTrj8cK6ET1Jo5OTKbKTrglSKbK4Kl4fH4AhqKVJWR92ZzuSoAUCPlIBHQ6CAUGBsA4gA)